# Generalization of Euler's totient theorem (aka Fermat–Euler theorem)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I am solving some math competition questions, and I realized that I do not know of a rigorous solution for this problem:

> What is the units digit of $2^{2015}$?

We can easily see that the units digits of $2^n$ just cycles around the digits 2, 4, 8, and 6. So the units digit is 8.

Upon trying to use the Euler's totient theorem to write a rigorous proof, I realized that 2 and 10 are not relatively prime.

Question: Is there a way to modify the theorem to go about this?

Comment: Sure. Work modulo $5$. Modulo $2$ the answer is obvious, now put things together.

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem is what could be used in all of these cases.

Comment: Not quite right. By the Fermat/Euler Theorem, $2^{2012}\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, so $2^{2015}\equiv 2^3\pmod{5}$. So we get $8$ (or if one wishes, $3$ modulo $5$. To get $\equiv 0\pmod{2}$ use $8$.

Comment: The fact that $2^n$ is periodic mod $10$ is *already* a rigorous proof, given that multiplication is well defined mod $10$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ x\equiv a\pmod 5\iff x\equiv a,\,a\!+\!5\pmod{10}.\,$ In your case you know $\,x\,$ is even so you choose from $\,a,\,a\!+\!5$ the even one to lift the solution up (CRT is overkill for such a simple thing).